# creating a matrix with zero and one

Tags: r, matrix, zero

I have this data:

```
A <- c("G", "C", "K")
B <- c("S", "B", "A")
C <- c("A", "M", "C")
```

And I have this matrix.

```
      [A]   [B]  [C]
[1,]    T    S    R
[2,]    Y    N    C
[3,]    G    U    N
[4,]    C    Z    Q
[5,]    S    D    K
[6,]    M    A    M
[7,]    S    B    F
[8,]    K    J    A
```

My idea is to create a new heatmap 8 rows x 3 columns where in each columns if rows don't contains letters in variables, I give zero. On the contrary, if the letter correspond of which contained in variables, a 1 appers. I would to obtain something like this:

```
       [A]   [B]  [C]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0
[6,]    0    1    1
[7,]    0    1    0
[8,]    1    0    1
```

Could you suggest me a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to use `mapply` to simultaneously iterate over the columns of the matrix and elements of `list(A, B, C)`

```
mapply(function(col, vec) +(col %in% vec), as.data.frame(mat), list(A, B, C))
#     A B C
#[1,] 0 1 0
#[2,] 0 0 1
#[3,] 1 0 0
#[4,] 1 0 0
#[5,] 0 0 0
#[6,] 0 1 1
#[7,] 0 1 0
#[8,] 1 0 1
```

Explanation: `col %in% vec` checks for matching entries from `vec` in the column vector of the matrix. The unary operator `+` converts `TRUE`/`FALSE` to `1`/`0`.

---

Or even shorter (thanks @thelatemail)

```
+mapply(`%in%`, as.data.frame(mat), list(A, B, C))
```

---

### Sample data

```
A <- c("G", "C", "K")
B <- c("S", "B", "A")
C <- c("A", "M", "C")
mat <- matrix(c(
    "T", "Y", "G", "C", "S", "M", "S", "K",
    "S", "N", "U", "Z", "D", "A", "B", "J",
    "R", "C", "N", "Q", "K", "M", "F", "A"),
    ncol = 3)
colnames(mat) <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

Comment: You could collapse to `mapply(\`%in%\`, as.data.frame(mat), list(A, B, C)) + 0` or even `mapply(is.element, as.data.frame(mat), list(A, B, C)) + 0` if you want to avoid the backticks for `%in%`

Comment: @thelatemail Ah very neat; unary `+` works here too: `+mapply(\`%in%\`, as.data.frame(mat), list(A, B, C))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
+(map2_dfr(asplit(mat, 2), list(A, B, C), `%in%`))
#   A B C
#1 0 1 0
#2 0 0 1
#3 1 0 0
#4 1 0 0
#5 0 0 0
#6 0 1 1
#7 0 1 0
#8 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I´d bet there is a simpler solution, but the following works.

mat1 is the letter matrix.

mat2 is the binary (1,0) matrix.

The function contains(x,y) takes x, the character vector you want to test and y, the column name as a string and subsequently checks the column.

```
A <- c("G", "C", "K")
B <- c("S", "B", "A")
C <- c("A", "M", "C")
mat1 <- matrix(c("T","S", "R", "Y", "N", "C", "G", "U", "N", "C", "Z", "Q", "S", "D", "K", "M", "A", "M", "S", "B", "F", "K", "J", "A"), nrow = 8, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c(1:8), c("A", "B", "C")), byrow=TRUE)
mat2 <- matrix(0L, nrow = 8, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c(1:8), c("A", "B", "C")))

row_count <- 1
contains <- function(x, y){
  for (i in mat1[,y]){
    if (i %in% x){
      mat2[row_count,y] <<- 1
    }
    row_count <<- row_count +1
  }
}


contains(A, "A")
contains(B, "B")
contains(C, "C")
```

Hope that helps,
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For your matrix `M`, the following may help you:

```
sapply(colnames(M), function(x) as.numeric(!is.na(match(M[,x],eval(parse(text = x))))))
```